# Does Friedmann fluid equation prove that energy of the fluid is not conserved?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, pressure, energy-conservation, space-expansion

The [Friedmann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations) in question is:$$
\dot\rho  + 3H \left(ρ + P\right) = 0
\,.$$
I’m a layperson so I don’t know why this equation is sometimes called fluid equation, energy conservation equation, or continuity equation.

Does this equation prove that energy is not conserved in an expanding universe since it shows that the energy of a fluid with negative pressure will increase with the expansion; the energy of a fluid with positive pressure will decrease with the expansion?

Is it well established that this equation correctly describes the relation between pressure and energy density of fluids (with zero, positive, negative pressure) in an expanding universe? If so, it could be a definite proof that energy is not conserved in an expanding universe.